# Compare two csv files in C#

Tags: c#, csv

I want to compare two csv files and print the differences in a file. I currently use the code below to remove a row. Can I change this code so that it compares two csv files or is there a better way in c# to compare csv files?

```
  List<string> lines = new List<string>();
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(System.IO.File.OpenRead(path)))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line.Contains(csvseperator))
                {
                     string[] split = line.Split(Convert.ToChar(scheidingsteken));

                    if (split[selectedRow] == value)
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        line = string.Join(csvseperator, split);
                        lines.Add(line);
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path, false))
        {
            foreach (string line in lines)
                writer.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you want to find out *added*, *deleted* and *changed* lines, please have a look at the *edit distance* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance

Comment: I can't use that.

Comment: Why are you so sad? Why can't you use it? The easiest edit distance (*Levenshtein* one) is easy to implement 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Comment: You really shouldn't use empty `if` blocks in your code. Changing the condition solves this issue.

Comment: What do you want your program to output when two CSV files contain exactly the same data, but in a different order? Also, do records need to match 100%? Or is `1,Pete,2` equal to `1,"Pete",2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to compare one column you can use this code:

```
                List<string> lines = new List<string>();
    List<string> lines2 = new List<string>();



    try
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(System.IO.File.OpenRead(pad));
        StreamReader read = new StreamReader(System.IO.File.OpenRead(pad2));

        string line;
        string line2;

        //With this you can change the cells you want to compair
        int comp1 = 1;
        int comp2 = 1;

        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null && (line2 = read.ReadLine()) != null)
        {           
            string[] split = line.Split(Convert.ToChar(seperator));
            string[] split2 = line2.Split(Convert.ToChar(seperator));

            if (line.Contains(seperator) && line2.Contains(seperator))
            {
                if (split[comp1] != split2[comp2])
                {
                    //It is not the same
                }
                else
                {
                    //It is the same

                }
            }
        }
        reader.Dispose();
        read.Dispose();
    }
    catch
    {

    }
```

Comment: This only checks the 2nd column of each line, and ignores lines if one CSV contains more lines than the other.

Comment: How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way to find differences between CSV files, using [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL/) - an open source library

For the below sample CSV files

**sample1.csv**

```
id,name
1,Tom
2,Mark
3,Angie
```

**sample2.csv**

```
id,name
1,Tom
2,Mark
4,Lu
```

**METHOD 1:**

Using Cinchoo ETL, below code shows how to find differences between rows by all columns

```
var input1 = new ChoCSVReader("sample1.csv").WithFirstLineHeader().ToArray();
var input2 = new ChoCSVReader("sample2.csv").WithFirstLineHeader().ToArray();

using (var output = new ChoCSVWriter("sampleDiff.csv").WithFirstLineHeader())
{
    output.Write(input1.OfType<ChoDynamicObject>().Except(input2.OfType<ChoDynamicObject>(), ChoDynamicObjectEqualityComparer.Default));
    output.Write(input2.OfType<ChoDynamicObject>().Except(input1.OfType<ChoDynamicObject>(), ChoDynamicObjectEqualityComparer.Default));
}
```

**sampleDiff.csv**

```
id,name
3,Angie
4,Lu
```

**Sample fiddle:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/nwLeJ2

**METHOD 2:**

If you want to do the differences by `id` column,

```
var input1 = new ChoCSVReader("sample1.csv").WithFirstLineHeader().ToArray();
var input2 = new ChoCSVReader("sample2.csv").WithFirstLineHeader().ToArray();

using (var output = new ChoCSVWriter("sampleDiff.csv").WithFirstLineHeader())
{
    output.Write(input1.OfType<ChoDynamicObject>().Except(input2.OfType<ChoDynamicObject>(), new ChoDynamicObjectEqualityComparer(new string[] { "id" })));
    output.Write(input2.OfType<ChoDynamicObject>().Except(input1.OfType<ChoDynamicObject>(), new ChoDynamicObjectEqualityComparer(new string[] { "id" })));
}
```

**Sample fiddle:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/t6mmJW

Comment: This is a great tool. Thank you. In my case I have a "master" CSV file and a "detail" CSV file. How can I do the same above where CSV 1 is the master and CSV 2 is the detail to ouput a file saying record '3' has been "deleted" and record "4" is new? Obviously a new column to show this status. Could you please add an example to your answer? Oh and my CSVs have a unique ID column like your samples. Appreciated.

Comment: Here u go https://dotnetfiddle.net/LIHZBv

Comment: @Chinchoo Where does the result file get stored to?

Comment: can be routed to file, stream etc.