# C# WPF Compare 2 CSV files and output differences into new csv file

Tags: c#, csv

I have a WPF application with a csv file that gets displayed in a texbox when the application is loaded, like so:

```
        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            path = @"C:\Users\user\Documents\app\mainFile.csv";

            mainFile = File.ReadAllText(path);

            txtDisplay.Text = mainFile;
        }
```

Also, I have 2 buttons: Upload and Compare. The upload button has the following code:

```
        private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            if(openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                compareFile = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog.FileName);
                MessageBox.Show("File Uploaded");
            }
        }
```

Once a file is uploaded it gets stored in the `compareFile` variable. What I want to do is, once the compare button is clicked, the 2 files (`mainFile` and `compareFile`) to be compared and output the **non-matching** lines into another CSV file. I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction to solving this, I have little to no programming experience, so any help is appreciated.

Here are the CSV files just in case you needed to see the format:

**compareFile**

```
id,firstname,lastname,email,city
10,Jaime,Odell,Jaime.Odell@yopmail.com,Lagos
11,Charlena,Birdella,Charlena.Birdella@yopmail.com,Liverpool
12,Kristan,Phaidra,Kristan.Phaidra@yopmail.com,Innsbruck
13,Annecorinne,Lay,Annecorinne.Lay@yopmail.com,San Juan
14,Dotty,Sidonius,Dotty.Sidonius@yopmail.com,Curitiba
15,Mellicent,Maurine,Mellicent.Maurine@yopmail.com,Rio de Janeiro
16,Bill,Khorma,Bill.Khorma@yopmail.com,Dongguan
17,Kary,Nicoline,Kary.Nicoline@yopmail.com,Zagreb
18,Karena,Martguerita,Karena.Martguerita@yopmail.com,Mexico City
19,Antonietta,Thunell,Antonietta.Thunell@yopmail.com,Kandy
```

**mainFile**

```
id,firstname,lastname,email,city
10,Jaime,Odell,Jaime.Odell@yopmail.com,Lagos
11,Charlena,Birdella,Charlena.Birdella@yopmail.com,Liverpool
12,Kristan,Phaidra,Kristan.Phaidra@yopmail.com,Innsbruck
13,Keelia,Callista,Keelia.Callista@yopmail.com,Gibraltar
14,Binny,Boycey,Binny.Boycey@yopmail.com,Adelaide
15,Therine,Euridice,Therine.Euridice@yopmail.com,Shenyang
16,Belinda,Olympium,Belinda.Olympium@yopmail.com,Maseru
17,Kary,Nicoline,Kary.Nicoline@yopmail.com,Zagreb
18,Karena,Martguerita,Karena.Martguerita@yopmail.com,Mexico City
19,Antonietta,Thunell,Antonietta.Thunell@yopmail.com,Kandy
```

Comment: does it help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46688563/compare-two-csv-files-in-c-sharp

Comment: Looks like what I need, but I am unable to install it on visual studio, says: Package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. What version of .NET do i need?

Comment: .net framework 4.5+,  .net core 2.x, .net standard